# Blank White Screen Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, screen

I was working in my functions.php file, and i was trying to comment something out and when i refreshed the page it was all blank. Not only my website but also my /wp-admin page.

I have tried re-downloading my themes function.php and replacing it but this hasn't worked.

Please help!

Comment: try adding define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); to your config file for any errors

Comment: When i opened my wp-config.php file there was nothing there so I added it in but all that does is show exactly what i type on the blank page... then i realised that i hadnt added in <?php ?> so did that but still just shows a blank page?

Comment: Do you have a link to test?

Comment: yes, wwww.basechurch.org.zw

Answer (score 0):

open your wp-config.php and find

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

set it to

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

it will show which file is causing problem, Its a starting level to check white screen problem in wordpress otherwise you can follow Ahmad's answer

Comment: When i opened my wp-config.php file there was nothing there so I added it in but all that does is show exactly what i type on the blank page... then i realised that i hadnt added in <?php ?> so did that but still just shows a blank page?

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall your all plugins by renaming the plugins folder , ie plugins1.
And also change the theme and try. If not work then Go to following link.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/fixing-the-wordpress-white-screen-of-death--cms-21008